# SQL Server Global Temp Table Still Exist After Drop

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm currently trying to run some query in SQL Server. Inside the query there is a part like this:

```
...
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects 
          WHERE id = object_id(N'tempdb.dbo.[##Emp]')) 
    DROP TABLE ##Emp   

SELECT * 
INTO ##Emp 
FROM #Emp (nolock)
...
```

The thing is I keep getting some error that says `##Emp` already exists. How is this thing possible when I already checked it with `IF EXIST DROP`? I even tried to remove the `IF EXIST` part and manually drop the table, but it still says that the table is already exists.

Comment: `if object_id('tempdb..[##Emp]') is not null` drop it.

Comment: I was not able to repro the same issue,may be in some part of code you are trying to create again same table

Comment: or may be some other session also creating them parallely

Comment: It's exceedingly rare for a global temp table to actually be the right solution to a problem - can you tell us what *problem* you were trying to solve that made a global temp table look like it fitted in as part of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check **both** the temp table statuses with a simple:

```
select * from tempdb..sysobjects where name like '%Emp%'
```

Then be shure to handle deletion and recreation for **both**:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ...
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'tempdb..[#Emp]'))
        DROP TABLE #Emp
    CREATE TABLE #Emp(exampleId uniqueidentifier);
    ...
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'tempdb.dbo.[##Emp]')) 
        DROP TABLE ##Emp   

    SELECT * 
    INTO ##Emp 
    FROM #Emp
    ...
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

As @damien-the-unbeliever pointed out a globally visible temporary table can be quite troublesome, double check if you really need it.
In this case it's also very confusing to have such similar names...